# Magento Json Serializer vs native PHP

Tags: magento2, json, serialize, framework

Is there any special reason why I should use the Magento framework classes such as JSON Serializer vs just native PHP?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

For example, I would tend to use native PHP as then I don't need to use any dependency injection for something which is already available to me